Number of bins and labels do not match in matplotlib
I have a customize legend in my matplotlib but for some reason I cannot get the bins and the labels to match. If I add one more label, it starts to complaint that I have to many labels in comparison to my bins. How can I change the labeling so that the black lines of the labels are exactly in the correct position (in between two bins) and so that the number of labels in increased with 1?
Below my example code:
data = {
'country': ['United States', 'China', 'India', 'Brazil', 'Australia'],
    '(LU (PDF)': [0.00000001, 0.0000001, 0.0000005, 0.000001, 0.00001]
}

fabio_country = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Load the world map data
world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))

# Merge the world map with your DataFrame
world = world.merge(fabio_country, left_on='name', right_on='country', how='left')

# Define your bins
bins = [0, 0.000000001, 0.00000001, 0.0000001, 0.000001, 0.00001, 0.0001, 0.001]

labels = ['0', '0.000000001', '0.00000001', '0.0000001', '0.000001', '0.00001', '0.0001', '0.001']

# Classify the data
world['binned'] = pd.cut(world['LU (PDF)'], bins=bins, labels=labels, include_lowest=True)

# Convert to Robinson projection
world = world.to_crs('ESRI:54030')

# Plotting
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(15, 10))
world.boundary.plot(ax=ax)
cmap = plt.get_cmap('OrRd', len(labels))
norm = Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=len(labels)-1)
world.plot(column='binned', ax=ax, legend=False, cmap=cmap, norm=norm, edgecolor='black')

# Create a horizontal legend
sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
sm.set_array([])
cbar = plt.colorbar(sm, orientation='horizontal', fraction=0.046, pad=0.04)
cbar.set_ticks(range(len(labels)))
cbar.set_ticklabels(labels)
cbar.set_label('PDF')

plt.title('Biodiversity loss caused by land use in PDF')
plt.show()



Try changing:
norm = Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=len(labels)-1)

...


cbar.set_ticks(range(len(labels)))

to instead be:
vmax = len(labels) - 2  # this will normalise to values from 0 and 6 inclusive
norm = Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=vmax)

...

cbar.set_ticks(np.linspace(0, vmax, len(labels)))

